# Solution to pause and resume in RxJava similar to TestCoroutineScope

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

Full source code is available at : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/StarWarsSearch-RxPaging

Here is my local unit test where I test a ViewModel while I am using Coroutines for networking :

```
@Test
fun givenServerResponse200_whenFetch_shouldReturnSuccess() {
    testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
        `when`(api.fetchShowList()).thenReturn(emptyList())
    }

    val repository = ShowRepository(dao, api, context, TestContextProvider())

    testCoroutineRule.pauseDispatcher()

    val viewModel = MainViewModel(repository)

    assertThat(viewModel.shows.value, `is`(Resource.loading()))

    testCoroutineRule.resumeDispatcher()

    assertThat(viewModel.shows.value, `is`(Resource.success(emptyList())))
}
```

As you know I can pause and resume using TestCoroutineScope, so I can test when liveData is in Loading or Success state.

I wonder if we can do the same thing when we test while we are using RxJava.

At the moment I just can verify Success state :

```
@Test
fun givenServerResponse200_whenFetch_shouldReturnSuccess() {
    `when`(repository.getSpecie(anyString())).thenReturn(Single.just(specie))
    `when`(repository.getPlanet(anyString())).thenReturn(Single.just(planet))
    `when`(repository.getFilm(anyString())).thenReturn(Single.just(film))

    viewModel = DetailViewModel(schedulerProvider, character, 
               GetSpecieUseCase(repository), GetFilmUseCase(repository))

    viewModel.liveData.value.let {
        assertThat(it, `is`(notNullValue()))
        if (it is Resource.Success) {
            it.data?.let { data ->
                assertTrue(data.films.isNotEmpty())
                assertTrue(data.species.isNotEmpty())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in ViewModel init block, I send the network request. You can review it in the bellow class. That can be tested using pause and resume while using Coroutines. How about RxJava?

```
open class BaseViewModel<T>(
    private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider,
    private val singleRequest: Single<T>
) : ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<T>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<T>>
        get() = _liveData

    init {
        sendRequest()
    }

    fun sendRequest() {
        _liveData.value = Resource.Loading
        singleRequest.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui()).subscribe({
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(it))
            }) {
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Error(it.localizedMessage))
                Timber.e(it)
            }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `TestScheduler` to some extent but unless you have timed steps in the flow, it would run all available work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I understood Using RxJava’s TestScheduler, time stands still until you call `advanceTimeBy()`, but how can it work in my case where `sendRequest` method is in init block of ViewModel. Can you explain your suggestion as an answer with the codes that you recommend in my case. As you see I have no `Observable.interval`, I do not want to test if delays or timeouts in my code works as expected.

Comment: Make `schedulerProvider.ui()` and `schedulerProvider.io()` return a `TestScheduler` you also can reference, then replace `testCoroutineRule.resumeDispatcher()` with `testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Comment: I have tried it. If I return TestScheduler, all test cases will be passed without checking the result of actual and expected value in assertions. Is that something that I missed? [Here](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/StarWarsSearch-RxPaging/blob/master/feature_search/src/test/java/com/android/sample/feature/search/DetailViewModelTest.kt) are my test cases.

Comment: Where is the code you changed to use the `TestScheduler` I suggested?

Comment: I tried importing your project but it fails with various plugin errors on a fresh Android Studio install.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I just simply return TestScheduler instead of Schedulers.trampoline() in [this clsss](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/StarWarsSearch-RxPaging/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/android/sample/common/util/schedulers/ImmediateSchedulerProvider.kt). I will try to import the project on a fresh Android Studio to see the plugins error and return back to you.

Comment: Looking at the tests, they always pass because you have assertions if the livedata value is of a specific type but no fail option. The init sets the livedata value to Resource.Loading and stays that way unless the scheduled code is actually triggered.

Comment: Exactly. You mention to use `testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` but that does not triggered the scheduled code. BTW I have a suggestion to : Return `Single.just(specie).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)` to test the loading state and then `testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to test Success or Error state. I tried that and it worked. What is your opinion about that? Is that fine?

Comment: For error case I return : ``when`(repository.getSpecie(anyString())).thenReturn(
                Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
                        .flatMap { Single.error(Exception("error")) })` Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: See the [PR](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/StarWarsSearch-RxPaging/pull/1/files) I submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as expected. You are more than welcome to share your comments as an answer and I mark it as accepted. Your solution looks better than mine in the above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what you tried, I can only guess there were two possible issues that required fixing:

1. Use the same `TestScheduler` for all provider methods:

   ```kotlin
   class ImmediateSchedulerProvider : BaseSchedulerProvider {

       val testScheduler = TestScheduler()

       override fun computation(): Scheduler = testScheduler

       override fun io(): Scheduler = testScheduler

       override fun ui(): Scheduler = testScheduler
   }
   ```
2. The unit tests weren't failing for the wrong state so they appear to pass even when the code hasn't run:

   ```kotlin
   @Test
   fun givenServerResponse200_whenFetch_shouldReturnSuccess() {
       `when`(repository.getSpecie(anyString())).thenReturn(Single.just(specie))
       `when`(repository.getPlanet(anyString())).thenReturn(Single.just(planet))
       `when`(repository.getFilm(anyString())).thenReturn(Single.just(film))

       viewModel = DetailViewModel(schedulerProvider, character, GetSpecieUseCase(repository),
               GetPlanetUseCase(repository), GetFilmUseCase(repository))

       viewModel.liveData.value.let {
           assertThat(it, `is`(Resource.Loading))
       }

       schedulerProvider.testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // <-------------

       viewModel.liveData.value.let {
           assertThat(it, `is`(notNullValue()))
           if (it is Resource.Success) {
               it.data?.let { data ->
                   assertTrue(data.films.isNotEmpty())
                   assertTrue(data.species.isNotEmpty())
               }
           } else {
               fail("Wrong type " + it)  // <---------------------------------------------
           }
       }
   }
   ```